# Open Sakura in home directory

Tags: terminal, sakura

I love XTerm but I would like to enable tabbing (multiple terminals in one window separated by tabs).

The terminal Sakura is based on XTerm and tabbing is enabled.

I can open XTerm in my home directory by executing `xterm -e 'cd ~/ && /bin/bash'`. However, this doesn't work with Sakura (I replaced `xterm` by `sakura`). I also tried `sakura -e 'cd ~/'` but it doesn't work either.

How can I open a shell in Sakura in my home directory?

Comment: Doesn't it have a man page you can refer to?

Comment: The man page is not helpful. It merely states that the flag -e executes a command.

Answer (score 2):

Sakura is most certainly *not* based on xterm. It is in fact yet another VTE terminal. The source claims that the -e option is compatible, but clearly is not (xterm uses a shell, for one thing. Also, it doesn't appear to do the "all arguments" nonsense that sakura's source claims it does and emulates with its -e option).

From looking at the source for how it deals with command line arguments, try this:

```
sakura -x 'sh -c "cd ~; exec /bin/bash"'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question. I tried your suggestion and it leads to progress. The Sakura terminal I get opens no longer as a blank window but in the root directory. How do go to the home directory?

Answer (score 1):

`sakura -d ~` works for me, the -d flag let you choose the directory you want it to open in.